# 3d plot superstore data

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

How to make out of the below dataset a very meaningful/insightful 3D Plot. I mean, which variables you will pick up, plus, which 3D plot you will choose?
Also, if you can add the same for the boxplot.

[image: First Half Columns]

[image: Second Half Columns]